# screen share not working in Ubuntu 22.04, showing black screen with Slack, Google meet etc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, slack, google-meet

Facing screen share not working in `Ubuntu 22.04`, showing as black screen with `Slack`, `Google meet` and other teams connecting platforms.

Answer (score 21):

Solution:
Go to this file,

`sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

uncomment this line,

`WaylandEnable=false`

Reboot your machine.

Comment: In my situation, I experienced a problem when I uncommented ***WaylandEnable=false***. This resulted in the malfunctioning of my input devices such as the keyboard and mouse. Hence, I would advise against implementing this solution. It's crucial to exercise caution when utilizing this command.

Comment: Solution which worked for me I found here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407494/screen-share-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04-in-all-platforms-zoom-teams-google-m
as a second answer
**Only works for web browser
Go to chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer using the address bar of your browser.**

Comment: This isn't a solution to screen sharing in Wayland. This simply disables Wayland, and that is going to be deprecated going forward.

Comment: WARNING: This broke my OS, I had to erase the disk and reinstall it

Comment: @siride Xorg is not "deprecated". It is still required for many things to work that don't work on Wayland.

Comment: @Wes It can be deprecated and still be used for a long time. The X.org developers have moved on to working on Wayland and the plan is to have it replace X11 entirely. Whether that takes 6 months or 6 decades is irrelevant to whether it is deprecated (which it is).

Comment: Disabling Wayland is not a solution.